# How can you hide shared folders from those who do not have permissions in Window server 2016 without Active directory

Tags: shared-folders, sharing, access-based-enumeration

I am using window server 2016 without active directory. I have created some shared folder for users in the server but when users are accessing their folder they are able to see the folder of all other users. I have enable access based enumeration as shown in the following image but still folders are visible for all users.
[Click here to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dpvjg.jpg)
Please help how to solve it.

Comment: How exactly are users access these folders? Are they logging on to the server and browsing the local folder structure, e.g. `c:\SharedData` or are they browsing a network share via UNC path? E.g. `\\server\share`

Comment: Thank you for your quick response Wrecclesham, yes users have user name and password in server and they are accessing network share \\server\shareFolder. I do not want to use $ in the end of folder name which will hide the folder.

Comment: Are the users each accessing different network shares? E.g. `\\server\user1`, `\\server\user2` etc? I.e. one share per user? OR are the users all accessing the same network share but each has access to a different folder within that same share? Eg ``\\server\share\folder1`, ``\\server\share\folder2` etc?

Comment: I'm assuming that the answer to my previous question is that multiple users access the same share but your question reads like there are *multiple* shares (one per user?) so it's hard to fully understand your situation from the question so far. 

Comment: hank you for your response Wrecclesham,  Yes it is one share per user E.g. \\server\user1, \\server\user2

Comment: Interesting. So users are viewing the server's list of shares with `\\server` and seeing all of the other user shares listed that way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I do not want to use $ in the end of folder name which will hide the folder.

Access-based enumeration is only designed to hide files and folders *within* a share, rather than to hide shares themselves. This is why your users are currently able to view the shares which they do not have access to, despite ABE being enabled.

Unfortunately, in this situation, the only option to hide shares from users is by converting them to hidden shares by appending a `$` to every network share that you wish to hide.

There is no solution here that involves ABE as that option is powerless to prevent network shares from being enumerated.

ABE is designed to only act on the *contents* of shares and cannot actually prevent shares themselves from being listed.

Answer (score -2):

here is your answer : https://www.windowscrush.com/hide-shared-folders-from-those-who-do-not-have-permissions.html
you need to create a top shared directory containing different directories on which you setup the correct NTFS access for each groups/users.

basically, there a special checkbox for what you need "enable access-based enumeration".
On the server windows 2016, Server Manager > File and Storage Services > Shares :
 right-click the top Shared directory > properties and inside "Settings" check "enable access-based enumeration"

Comment: Please quote and cite relevant information from your link.